In python argparse package when adding "formatter_class" MetavarTypeHelpFormatter the "--help" is not working any more
I'm using the python package argparse,
with simple configuration
When I try to add to my parser formatter_class=argparse.MetavarTypeHelpFormatter I get error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'

did anyone else encounter that? and maybe know why?
this is my code:
import argparse

argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.MetavarTypeHelpFormatter
)

argParser.add_argument("models", default='', nargs='+',
                       help="Which model(s) to execute")


args = argParser.parse_args()
print(args)

When I try it with out adding the formatter_class it is working
It is also working with other formatter class like formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
I also tried it with prog attribute and without

MetavarTypeHelpFormatter class is not widely used. It's a simple modification of the base formatter.  As the answers show the problem lies with how the default type is implemented.  That works fine for other purposes,

Short answer: the type argument to add_argument defaults to None, not str.

Less short answer: a type of None behaves like a type of str, but doesn't work with MetaVarTypeHelpFormatter.
MetaVarTypeHelpFormatter requires an explicit type for each argument.
argParser.add_argument("models", default='', nargs='+', type=str,
                   help="Which model(s) to execute")

Its documented purpose is to use the name of the argument's type attribute as the metavariable, and that attribute defaults to None.
Although the default type of an argument is str, that just means the str value taken from the argument list is preserved if the argument's type attribute is None, or converted to the given type if it is not None.
>>> p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> print(p.add_argument("foo").type)
None
>>> print(p.add_argument("foo", type=int).type)
<class 'int'>


Each parser maintains a type registry, which means you can add your own arbitrary mappings of values to callables to produce types. For instance,
>>> import argparse
>>> p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> p.register('type', 'lowercase', lambda x: x.lower())
>>> p.add_argument("foo", type='lowercase')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type='lowercase', choices=None, required=True, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> p.parse_args(["HELLO WORLD"])
Namespace(foo='hello world')

Initially, the entry in the type registry maps None to
def identity(string):
    return string

which is why an argument with "type" None otherwise behaves as if you had supplied str explicitly.
The type registry isn't documented and, aside from this single entry, isn't used again, so it's not clear why it exists. The author may have had plans to use it more that never came to fruition. (Notice that each parser also has an action registry that gets used more often, which is why you can specify actions like 'append' and 'store_const' instead of specifying non-public classes like _AppendAction and _StoreConstAction directly.)

From the Python docs:

MetavarTypeHelpFormatter uses the name of the type argument for each argument as the display name for its values (rather than using the dest as the regular formatter does)

So, you need to add the argument for instance as
p.add_argument('models', default='', nargs='+', help='no help', type=str) 

But it's really a bug in argparse that it throws an exception later: it should have raised this exception immediately when you added the argument without specifying the type.

type as a default None aka str works fine for parsing. It's just that this Formatter subclass takes a too simplistic approach to fetching a default metavar. I don't think this Formatter subclass gets used very much

There isn't a problem with using nargs='+'.  It's with your test case.  parse_args should get a list of strings, e.g. p.parse_args(['abc xyz']) or p.parse_args('abc xyz'.split())

You'r right - I forgot about that.

I've removed the comment about nargs='+' from my earlier post.

You need to pass type= in add_argument:

MetavarTypeHelpFormatter uses the name of the type argument for each
argument as the display name for its values

You didn't specify so it gets None.
Since it defaults too '' in your example you can do:
argParser.add_argument(
    "models",
    default="",
    nargs="+",
    help="Which model(s) to execute",
    type=str,
)


That sounds like a bug. type is already supposed to default to str for the default action, so it should behave like that even if the type is omitted. Extremely stupid if type=str can and should be omitted under normal circumstances (just like we omit action='store', required=True, etc.), but it's required for MetavarTypeHelpFormatter.

argparse is really flexibly; the type argument can be any value, not just a type, and the callable used to convert an argument is looked up in a registry. For whatever reason, the registry maps None to an identity function, rather than just mapping str to str.

(It's not clear why it's so flexible; nothing else seems to use the type registry, and it's not documented as something for users to augment. It's similar to the action registry that maps, e.g., a string like 'append' to the _AppendAction class, but much less used.)

My guess is type was added to the registry from the start, with the idea tbat more type strings could be added.  But apart from a few common fiunctions like int and float users don't use many special type functions.  Latter someone added this Metavar formatter, but didn't test it thoroughly.  Since it's so easy to specify a metavar, I'm not sure this subclass is needed (or used often). In any case if we make a change, it should be it the formatter subclass, not in the registry use. parser._getvalue handles the registry just fine.

p._get_value uses
type_func = self._registry_get('type', action.type, action.type)

which would return str for the default type.
This Formatter subclass instead uses
return action.type.__name__

to get the type, ignoring the _registry.
I agree that using the _registry for type probably is an under-utilized feature.  registry is mainly used for action.  It users want a custom type, they can define the necessary function, and use that directly.  No real need to add it to the registry.
In all my years following argparse issues, I don't recall seeing this problem before.  That suggests that few people have used MetavarTypeHelpFormatter, or if they have, they have been in the habbit of using type=str.  Setting metavar directly is also a good alternative.
Note, in the default Formatter, the default_metavar is derived from the action.dest, either as is or as upper case.
